# Which local process is connected to given server on given port?

Tags: networking, solaris, netstat

On Linux, I can simply:

```
netstat -ntp | grep server_ip:port
```

And I get PID and process name of the program that is making given connection.

But how do I do it on Solaris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Solaris 10 or later you could use the [socketsnoop.d](http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html) DTrace script. Otherwise `lsof` is probably your best bet, as Dan points out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `lsof`, it should work on Solaris as well (if you have it available). Try `lsof -i` for network-related info.

Comment: Good hint, but unfortunately, I don't have lsof there.

Answer (score 0):

This script will give you that information using standard Solaris commands. If you give no argument, it will list all open ports and if you give one, it will list the process having that port open:

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    pfexec pfiles /proc/* 2>/dev/null | nawk -v port=$1 '
    /^[0-9]/ { cmd=$0; type="unknown"; continue }
    $1 == "SOCK_STREAM" { type="tcp" }
    $1 == "SOCK_DGRAM" { type="udp" }
    $2 == "AF_INET" { if((port!="")&&($5!=port)) continue;
                      if(cmd!="") { printf("%s\n    %s:%s/%s\n",cmd,$3,$5,type); cmd="" }
                      else { printf("    %s:%s/%s\n",cmd,$3,$5,type); }}'
```